# What does connectMicroservice and startAllMicroservicesAsync in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I saw `connectMicroservice` and `startAllMicroservicesAsync` in the [appliactions](https://github.com/nartc/nx-microservice-docker/blob/main/apps/payment-service/src/main.ts#L23) that using nest code.

What they do?

I could'nt able to find information about them in [nestjs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics).

Answer (score 0):

Those methods are for a [hybrid application](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application) where you're running a regular HTTP server **and** and microservice server via the same server application

Answer (score 0):

The `connectMicroservice` method is used to start a microservice instance in the application additionally to the regular HTTP server.

The `startAllMicroservices` executes the initialization of all the microservices previously connected with the method `connectMicroservice`. Similarly `startAllMicroservicesAsync` method executes the initialization of all the microservices asynchronously to the HTTP server initialization.